# Is Hash::make function always return 60 characters in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I installed a fresh version of laravel 4.2, I am making a user table and I want to ask if the Hash::make function always return 60 characters so that I can make the password field data type CHAR(60).

Additional:
I'm using the default configurations of laravel.

Comment: 60 characters is enough Blowfish, for now.

Comment: Hello Jack, i'm using the default laravel config, encryption, etc. Do you mean fixed 60 characters? I just want to know if it returns EXACTLY ALWAYS 60 CHARACTERS.

Comment: Yeah, it will be fixed length output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from the [implementation](https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/master/BcryptHasher.php#L27):

```
$hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
```

It uses [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash) and according to the manual:

> Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier. The result will **always be a 60 character string**, or FALSE on failure.